# How lock a file in windows using c++?

Tags: c++, file, file-locking

How can I lock a file in windows to only current thread (no other threads from same process and no other processes) can access (read/write) the file?

If it is possible please tell me some *fcntl-like* solution (solution which locks file having its descriptor). But in any case other solutions are welcome too.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows, you can open a file with exclusive access with the API function `CreateFile` and specifying `0` as the share mode.  More details at [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Much better than my solution +1

Comment: If subsequent threads all use the `CreateFile` API (no passing of the returned file `HANDLE`), then the calls to `CreateFile` _should_ fail, if I understand the documentation correctly.  However, I've not tried to do this (inter-thread) specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Use the WinAPI call [LockFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Here is a example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of its use. However this will only protect you from other processes from touching your file, it still lets other threads in the same process use the file.

EDIT:
I did not see this was C++ sorry, I only know the inter thread c# solution, however that MSDN link can at least get you started on preventing other processes from touching your file.

Comment: Mihran: you can call that function from a C++ function. This is the Win32 C API.

Comment: Note that `LockFile` locks the file for exclusive use by a single process, but not by a single thread. To ensure the latter, you will have to build your own locking mechanism within the process.